# sanitize lattice axis labels for tikz device

Tags: r, knitr, lattice, tikz

I'm trying to knit a `lattice` `contourplot` into a PDF document using `knitr` and the `tikz` device but am getting an `Error in getMetricsFromLaTeX(TeXMetrics)` on compile. Here's the minimal reproducible example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<contourplot,dev='tikz',echo=FALSE>>=
library(lattice)
library(RCurl)
x <- getURL("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3966900/likelihoods.csv")
likelihoods <- read.csv(text=x)

cutoffs <- c(-    Inf,-2700,-1497,-1486.6,-1486.3,-1486.286,-1486.28513,-1486.285082,-1486.28508033,-1486.285080237,    Inf)
contourplot(ll ~ var1*var2,
                           data = likelihoods,
                           scales = list(y = list(log = 10)),
                           at=cutoffs,
                           label.style='align',
                           labels=as.character(cutoffs),
                           xlab='$\\\\\\sigma$')
@

\end{document}
```

The whole thing works if I remove the `scales` line (I assume it's the `^` in the axis labels that trips `tikz` up?) but looks like shit.

It also works if I add `sanitize=TRUE` to the chunk options and remove two backslashes from the `xlab` string. In this case, however, the axis label also gets sanitized and I don't get a LaTeX-typeset axis label.

How do I get *all* of this to work?

Comment: Any reason for not using ggplot? That works well with knitr. For example: `<<label, fig.cap="My caption", fig.pos="h", echo=FALSE, fig.align='center', fig.height = 3, fig.width=5, out.height = '3in', out.width='5in'>>=`, then the plot: `ggplot(blah) + theme_bw(base_size = 8)`.

Comment: I tried `ggplot` (a package I have loads more experience with than `lattice`) but never got the plot to look like the one above looks. But after playing around with this for a bit more, perhaps that was premature. This does almost exactly what I want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658088/custom-levels-in-ggplot2-contour-plot

Comment: You could use `scales = list(y = list(log=10, at=10**seq(5,15,5))))` or `scales = list(y = list(log=10, at=10**seq(5,15,5), label=sprintf("$10^{%d}$", seq(5,15,5))))` in `countourplot()`

Comment: I'm pretty happy with Andy's `ggplot` solution, but since your solution actually answers the original question, do you want to post it as an answer and collect the bounty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sanitize the axis labels, modify the `scales` argument in the following way:

```
# e-notation (like ggplot2)
scales = list(y = list(log=10, at=10**seq(5, 15, 5))))
```

or

```
scales = list(y = list(log=10, at=10**seq(5, 15, 5),
              label=sprintf("$10^{%d}$", seq(5, 15, 5))))
```

Answer (score 1):

As Andy Clifton suggests in comments, doing this with `ggplot` seems to be a hell of a lot easier than getting it to work with lattice:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<contourplot,dev='tikz',echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE>>=
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(RCurl)
x <- getURL("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3966900/likelihoods.csv")
likelihoods <- read.csv(text=x)

cutoffs <- c(-Inf,-2700,-1497,-1486.6,-1486.3,-1486.286,-1486.28513,-1486.285082,-1486.28508033,-1486.285080237,Inf)

v <- ggplot(likelihoods, aes(var1, var2, z = ll))
v <- v + stat_contour(breaks=cutoffs)
v <- v + scale_y_continuous(trans=log10_trans(),
                            breaks=c(1e-5,1e0,1e5,1e10,1e15,1e20),
                            expand = c(0, 0))
v <- v + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-3, 5),
                            expand = c(0, 0))
v <- v + theme_bw()
v <- v + ylab('$\\sigma$')
v
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note to self - answer the question rather than making a comment! Glad that worked though.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to steal your credit. Based on your comment I worked out the details in minutes and thought it'd be easiest to just post the solution. I'd be happy to delete my answer, let you repost it and award you the bounty.

Comment: No worries - only joking. I have no idea how you got it working, but you did, so it's all yours.